# Chromecast not recognizing USB flash drives of varying sizes and formats when connected via a USB hub

Tags: usb-flash-drive, chromecast

I just bought a [Chromecast with Google TV](https://store.google.com/gb/product/chromecast_google_tv_specs) device and want to expand its storage with a USB flash drive. The power supply Google provided is 5V 1.5A. Since my USB hub has no type C, I used another power supply which is 5V 2A.

Now the Chromecast can run normally but it cannot detect any of the attached USB flash drives.

I’ve tried USB flash drives of different capacities of 32G, 64G, 128G, 256G, and also try different file system formats for each of them, FAT32, NTFS, exFAT. All do not work.

What am I missing? Is there any way to get the Chromecast to recognize these USB flash drives?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have misunderstood what the USB port on your Chromecast is for.

The Chromecast with Google TV only has two ports, a HDMI port and a USB-C port. The HDMI port is for transmitting pictures and sound to your TV. The USB-C port is for power only. It is not wired up to accept data. This means you can't use it with a USB flash drive.

You can see this information on the [tech spec's page](https://store.google.com/gb/product/chromecast_google_tv_specs) for it on Google's shop.

[image: Screenshot of the Chromecasts product listing]

If you have content on a USB flash drive that you want to view on the TV you will have to plug it into the TV (assuming your TV has a USB port) and use your TV's built in software to navigate the drive and select the content you want to display.

Alternatively you can put the drive into a computer and use the functionality within the desktop version of Chrome to cast the desktop and drive content to your TV.

Comment: I think the port works for both power and data. In fact I've just bought a more expensive UGREEN hub and it works now. I can now use a pen drive of 256G for extra storage of the chromecast. The hub also has an ethernet port and I can have both wired and wifi connections to the chromecast now.

Comment: Fair enough. Remember to post that as an answer. Why would you need extra storage on the Chromecast anyway? It is designed to stream content. Are you sure the hub isn't acting like a media server and appearing on your network as such? I am convinced that it wouldn't have drivers to be able to access the ethernet.